# Tool to run hourly 404 scan of a list of pages

Tags: iis, sharepoint-2007, http-status-code-404

Is there any 404 scanner out there that can be set up to run automatically, either as a standalone tool or as a Windows Task?

I'm trying to track down some elusive 404 errors that show up in our site's Google Analytics report. I suspect that our CMS, MOSS 2007, is incorrectly trimming the scheme/host information from some external links when our content deployment runs, so links to `http://externalsite.com/SomeExternalPage.aspx` become relative links to non-existant pages: `/SomeExternalPage.aspx`.

I need to find a tool that will let me run hourly scans of the offending pages to see when/how often this is happening. I normally use Xenu Link Scanner for this type of thing, but it is not commandline scriptable. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could cobble something together using GNU Wget in a batch file or PowerShell script:

> http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

The pre-built windows binaries are here:

> http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm